# Proxy Authentication Required with cURL

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I would like to use a cURL function, but I'm behind a proxy, so I get an `HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required` error...

This is the php code I use:

```
$proxy_user = 'Michiel';
$proxy_pass = 'mypassword';
$proxy_url = 'myproxyurl:port';
$proxy = true;

$service_url = "https://www.myapiurltocall.com";
$service_user = 'user:password:FO';
$service_pass = 'password';

$ch = curl_init($service_url);

// Set proxy if necessary
if ($proxy) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_user.':'.$proxy_pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
}

// Set service authentication
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$service_user}:{$service_pass}");

// HTTP headers
$headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$proxy_user:$proxy_pass");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

//WARNING: this would prevent curl from detecting a 'man in the middle' attack
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

And I don't know what I do wrong... How can I get around this error?

Comment: assuming the `$proxy_user:$proxy_pass` are the correct values, if you are behind an office firewall the authentication credentials to be used would be that of an administrator and not your own...I've encountered something very similar in my work environment and that was the case for me as my normal credentials didn't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Yep, behind an office firewall. The $proxy_user and $proxy pass are 100% correct (I can use my webmail and communicator with these credentials, so...) The administrator of my PC or of the network you mean?

Comment: Ok, great! Please add it as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is what I'm mostly using :

```
function curlFile($url,$proxy_ip,$proxy_port,$loginpassw)
{
    //$loginpassw = 'username:password';
    //$proxy_ip = '192.168.1.1';
    //$proxy_port = '12345';
    //$url = 'http://www.domain.com';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Ok, great thanks! How would a password authentication (for `$url` itself) fit into this setup?

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  This is exactly what I was looking to build.  You've saved me quite a headache.

Comment: Thank You Very Much, You escaped me from infinite loop of googling

Comment: which username password we have to pass?

Comment: This helped me Thank you

Comment: Works Great. Thanks. Generally port numbers are 80 for http and 1080 for https.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use and it works perfectly:

```
$proxy = "1.1.1.1:12121";
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
$url = "http://www.google.pt/search?q=anonymous";
$credentials = "user:pass"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,$credentials);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to implement this in your function

```
   function send_string($data) {
//       pr($data);exit;

     $equi_input="Your values";
//  echo $equi_input; exit;
        $agent = ""//Agent Setting for Netscape  
        $url = ""; // URL to POST FORM. (Action of Form)
        //xml format
         $efx_request=strtoupper($equi_input);
      //echo  $efx_request;exit;
        $post_fields = "site_id=""&service_name=""&efx_request=$efx_request";
        $credentials = ;
        $headers = array("HTTP/1.1",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization: Basic " . $credentials
        );
        $fh = fopen('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') or die("can't open file"); //File to write the header information of the curl request.
        $ch = curl_init();    // Initialize a CURL session.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // Pass URL as parameter.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // use this option to Post a form  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); // Pass form Fields.  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);  // grab URL and pass it to the variable.
        curl_close($ch);  // close curl resource, and free system resources.  
        fclose($fh);


   //echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';exit;
        if (!empty($result)) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            echo "Curl Error" . curl_error($ch);
        }
    }
```

check request send 200ok ...

And check your secure certificate if you are using....

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how to implement this in my current code. Could you help me out here?

Comment: i am also passing your variables value like credentials , Url ,Authorization .. i am passing authorization in $credentials variable .. i am passing username , password in postfield..,, read code , i think it will help you.

Comment: main thing first check your authentication credentials , may be that are creating problem for you... check ..

Comment: Please note a bug in the above code: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be an integer parameter, and should be set to 2 (the default). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more details. If you set the value to `true`, you're actually disabling host checking, and therefore enabling MITM attacks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `$proxy_user:$proxy_pass` are the correct values, if you are behind an office firewall the authentication credentials to be used would be that of a network administrator and not your own...I've encountered something very similar in my work environment and that was the case for me as my normal credentials didn't have the necessary privileges. The best way to ensure that this is the case however would be to ensure the code works in an open network with your proxy settings commented. Hope this helps!