# Download files from URL through a HTTPS proxy

Tags: php, image, proxy, download

I need to download images from both `http` and `https` protocols via a web proxy. This proxy needs authentication (it requires `username` and `password`). How can I do that? Currently I use the `copy` function of php to download files but I don't know how to set proxy for it. Thanks.

Comment: php-curl could be the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822211/proxy-authentication-required-with-curl

Comment: [Google the exact title of your question](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%3A+Download+files+from+URL+with+a+HTTPS+proxy) and look at the 4th result.

Comment: To be clear, I want a **secure** connection. I have tried the `curl` option provided in the link but I got the same `403` error which I would get without the proxy. This proxy is supposed to bypass a filtering system.

Comment: Please review the edit. I have included new code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using this code:

```
public static function dlFile($url)
{
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "IP:PORT");
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "USER:PASS");
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true); //IMPORTANT

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);

    curl_close($crl);

    return $ret;
}
```