# Including user and password for php stream socket proxy

Tags: php, zend-framework, proxy, stream-socket-client

I have a php script that connects to an smtp server and I pass the email address, password, and all the other stuff. (i'm using Zend)

I want to go through a proxy but my proxy server requires authentication. I've looked through the php documentation but I can't figure out where I put the username/password for the proxy server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you authenticate:

1. [cURL Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822211/proxy-authentication-required-with-curl)
2. [PHP stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#74431)