# PHP cURL GET Request Through SOCKS5 with Authentication

Tags: php, curl, socks

I'm trying to perform a web request through a SOCKS5 proxy with authentication, but it's not working and I can't work out why. Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'host:port');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

return curl_exec($ch);
```

When I use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`, it says the response code is `0`. Am I missing something obvious here? The proxy works fine with other programs I use, so I know it isn't an issue with the proxy.

Comment: Are redirects in action then use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` too and maybe you need an CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH opt. This is only a comment

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm afraid neither helped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822211/proxy-authentication-required-with-curl#9838699

Comment: Thanks. Same result as before.