# cURL on proxied localhost returns Access Denied

Tags: php, curl, proxy, localhost

I'm trying to access a `.php` file from another `.php` using `cURL`.

Both are on `localhost` and I'm using a `proxy`.

**THE PROBLEM**

If I try to access using postman or direct on the browser, the desired file returns correctly.

However, everytime that I try to access this file from another `.php` file using `cURL`, and passing all the proxy and auth values, it gives me the following:

> Access Denied (authentication_failed)
>
> Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
>   This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

Her is my cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy.myspecificproxy.com.br",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => "localhost/MyDesiredFile.php?param=test&mail=test%40test.com",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "myuser:mypassword123",
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => "8080",
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => 'HTTP',
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

Beyond trying to access via postman or browser, if I `cURL` directly from the command line, it works too.

**EDIT**

Tried to *disable the proxy for local addresses*, but no change in the result.

Comment: it's impossible to get a local host throught proxy

Comment: So, is there a way to test a file that request another file, locally?

Comment: without proxy, I think. But I never have used curl locally. Try to add protocol to URL.

Comment: @toor I tried without using proxy, but unafortunely it returns the same response `Access Denied (authentication_failed)` , being blocked by proxy again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy Authentication Required with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822211/proxy-authentication-required-with-curl)

Comment: you need to specify proxy port and proxy type as well.. command line parses the url into necessary fields but `curl` extension doesn't

Comment: @Lioo If you have a proxy enabled in your Internet settings, try to disable proxy for the local addresses

Comment: @Cemal target url is localhost. Proxy can't reach it.

Comment: instead of `CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy.myspecificproxy.com.br:8080",` you need to do `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => '8080', CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => 'HTTP', CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy.myspecificproxy.com.br'`

Comment: @toor if it had been the case, the commandline wouldn't have been able to access it as well. Regardless of how illogical it may seem, OP says it reaches from commandline. the localhost means the localhost of the server at proxy.myspecificproxy.com not on OP's machine.

Comment: @toor Disabled the proxy for local addresses, but keeps returning same result.

Comment: @Cemal Added theses additional options, but the result keeps the same. I'll edit the question with this info.

Comment: There atill is 8080 in CURLOPT_PROXY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a misconfiguration in the privileges.

I contacted the support team of the company and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a redirect involved? Remember that cURL doesn't follow redirects unless you tell it to, by passing the `--location` flag.

Does it work if you run it from the command line? Try that, and try passing `--verbose` and `--include` to see the returned headers.

Comment: No, there is no redirects. And yes, it works directly from the command line too, I'll edit the question adding this info.

Comment: @Ken how to get localhost from the Internet? Proxy is in the Internet...

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy.myspecificproxy.com.br",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => "localhost/MyDesiredFile.php?param=test&mail=test%40test.com",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "myuser:mypassword123",
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => "8080",
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => 'HTTP',
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Updated like you asked, but nothing changed in the return.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but no change in result.

Comment: it looks like your have something wrong in your Internet connection settings, such as a proxy record.